# Django 1.4 : static file not found

Tags: django

I try to google, but I can't fixed my problem. Many people have this problem and tried to follow their instruction, but I still can't fixed it. So, any problems with my configuration?

--- settings.py ----

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

---views.py---

```
render_to_response('authen/login.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

---login.html---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}styles/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}styles/root.css" />
```

---error---

```
[16/Apr/2012 21:27:26] "GET /authen/login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1391
[16/Apr/2012 21:27:26] "GET /static/styles/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1652
[16/Apr/2012 21:27:26] "GET /static/styles/root.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1649
```

---urls.py---

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
    )
```

Comment: Did you add the needed mapping in urls.py (assuming you're using the dev server and have DEBUG enabled) ?

Comment: Extended settings example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033571/using-static-files-with-the-django-virtual-server/11033706#11033706

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view

UPDATE: I see you have url pattern for static files. Do you have DEBUG=True in settings.py?

Comment: hmm, why do you have "GET /authen/login.php HTTP/1.1" in log when you defined login.html in urls?

Comment: I just copied it from terminal. Now I found it. I just set `STATIC_ROOT=''` and add `STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
)`. Thanks for your links.

Comment: The docs say "This view is automatically enabled by runserver (with a DEBUG setting set to True)." however I found that I needed to manually enable the staticfiles.views anyway. Any idea why that might be? Just a bug, or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it couldnt find any static file.
But With Sophy SEMs comment (see above) it worked:

Instead of setting

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
```

I've set

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static'), )
```

Then, it worked.
First I could'nt believe it makes any difference, but as I've retestet again, it is significant.

Comment: since STATICFILES_DIRS is served in DEV-Server / Debug, whereas STATIC_ROOT is not, since the latter is the (initially empty) target directory for collects for production.