# Using static files with the django virtual server

Tags: css, django, static-files, django-staticfiles

Questions exactly like this have been asked before, i've read them all and tried to make sense of the official django documentation on the subject but i'm still struggling to use static files on the virtual server. More specifically i'm just trying to get my template, `Base.html`, to use `base.css.`

My folder structure looks like this:

```
manage.py
static/CSS/base.css
VergeGreenITEvent_Website/settings.py
VergeGreenITEvent_Website/views.py ect
VergeGreenITEvent_Website/Webpage_Templates/Base.html
```

(no app folder at the moment, as I was following "The django book" to learn and hadn't gotten to that bit!)

**The complete settings.py can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/JB3mKRcJ**

In my Base.html template I now have the code:

```
<head>
    <title>Verge Green IT</title>
    {% load static %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "CSS/base.css" %}" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

CSS still isn't being applied.[image] Could you help me figure out what i'm doing wrong? I'd be incredibly grateful.

I'm using the latest version of Django. (1.4)

---

urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', views.Home),

)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() #this serves static files and media files.
    #in case media is not served correctly
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            }),
    )
```

Comment: STATIC_URL should be "/static/" I would avoid using caps in your directory naming, and please post your urls

Comment: @ArgsKwargs , thanks ive changed it to /static/. You mean the file urls.py? okay! but i'm not sure it will tell you much? The correct view is loaded fine and the html is all there, its just got no styling.

Comment: In your settings after **STATICFILES_DIRS = ( ... )** add **print STATICFILES_DIRS**, what does it show when you run the project. In your template what is the link that **{% static "CSS/base.css" %}** generates?

Comment: If you're using the new django project layout where settings is in a sub directory of the project, you need to use @noirbizarre his PROJECT_ROOT definition (using **'..'** to go up one dir)

Comment: ah thank you! That was exactly the cause! Thanks for talking me through and helping me debug @ArgsKwargs, i'll have a better idea of what to do in the future.

Comment: @ArgsKwargs, Can i be cheeky and ask you one more question? Now that i have a css working, how would i refer to an image from that CSS? assuming that images are stored in a subfolder of static like the CSS folder (`static/CSS/base.css`). In other words i want to use the file at `static/Images/background.gif` for a `background-image` property in my css. How does this work? i tried `{% load static %}` but that didn't work, presumably because the css file is static!

Comment: You cant use django filters in style sheets like that, you'll have to use hard coded paths or browse stackoverflow for dynamic style sheet solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Django 1.4 then I would use the static tag:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "CSS/base.css" %}" type="text/css" />
```

You probably need this in your urls too, in development files are served via django

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() #this serves static files and media files.
    #in case media is not served correctly
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            }),
    )
```

Also in your settings it's common practice to avoid hardcoding locations, here's an example (by the way do you have the static filefinders in your settings?

```
PROJECT_ROOT = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)) #gets directory settings is in

STATIC_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static-root')
# this folder is used to collect static files in production. not used in development

STATIC_URL =  "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('', path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')), #store site-specific media here.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # other processors...
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
)
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering! first question- is that bit of url.py you posted intended to replace the definition of urlpatterns i already have (now posted above)? Also i get the error "name 'settings' is not defined for that bit of code you posted.. I don't think i have filefinders in my settings, you can see the complete settings.py file here: http://pastebin.com/R8bKXkGB . I thought for testing purposed it might be easier to hardcode locations and then change once i know i had the folder structure right but i will try going through the settings you posted now..

Comment: Oh actually i do have both of those finders.

Comment: No those urlpatterns can be appended at the bottom of your urls file. At the top of the urls file add **from django.conf import settings**

Comment: Thanks so much for helping. I made all the changes to settings that you had in your example code and it seems to be allright but i'm still getting an error in urls.py, after importing settings - "name 'staticfiles_urlpatterns' is not defined"

Comment: You need to import functions before you can use them, so add **from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns** at the top

Comment: Ah right thanks (you can probably guess i'm new to django and python too). Good news is that i've not got any sort of errors, bad news is that my webpage is displayed but still isn't styled by the css. Does this screenshot of the cmd line help? http://i.imgur.com/8PUtt.png . does that mean it still can't find the base.css where it's looking?

Comment: Does **http://127.0.0.1/static/CSS/base.css** work in your browser? It seems the static path is not being found because it's looking for **/CSS/base.css**, did you add the static context processor so **{{ STATIC_URL }}** is available or are you using **{% load static %}**

Comment: No it doesn't work, neither does  127.0.0.1:8000/static/CSS/base.css. i used {% load static %} . Ive just tried STATIC_URL but still no styling. I'll just update my first question with all the lastest code..

Answer (score 0):

You should write your `settings.py` like that:

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'  # Should be root relative or absolute

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

# Where your static files will be collected with colletstatic command
# I use it only in deployed configuration with DEBUG=False
# Need to be outside STATICFILES_DIR
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/your.site'
```

Just to be sure, check with Firebug or webkit debugger that CSS is loaded.

Remember that Django won't serve your static files if `settings.DEBUG == False`.

Comment: *Don't* add `STATIC_ROOT` to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. That's not correct, and you shouldn't be recommending it. `STATIC_ROOT` is only for the output of `collectstatic` in production. It shouldn't even exist in development.

Comment: I'm using `STATIC_ROOT` as generic name for "the directory that you set `STATIC_ROOT` to", which pretty much always "static". Don't add the same directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. That's my point.

Comment: I don't understand: I don't do that anywhere.
It's just an exemple showing howto to declare STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_URL.
You read STATIC_ROOT instead of PROJECT_ROOT: I use it to have easy absolute paths declaration.

Comment: You are doing that because in your staticfiles_dirs tuple PROJECT_ROOT, 'static' results in the same location

Comment: I never set STATIC_ROOT to the same directory. I edited my response to reflect that.

Comment: I can't set the styles with Debug False and I can't upload to production with Debug True because it's a security issue. What should I do?