# Managing static files in Django

Tags: python, django

```
STATIC_ROOT = '%s/site_media' % PROJECT_DIR
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'images'),)
```

When I run 127.0.0.1:8000/static/something.jpg everything works.
But I want get something.jpg like this 127.0.0.1:8000/static/**images**/something.jpg

When I change STATICFILES_DIRS:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('',)
```

127.0.0.1:8000/static/**images**/something.jpg doesn't work, why?

Comment: Extended settings example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033571/using-static-files-with-the-django-virtual-server/11033706#11033706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, ''),)
```

Your STATIC_DIR should point to the project `site_media` dir. When adding `images'` to it, then `127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/something.jpg` is being searched in `.../site_media/images/images/something.jpg`

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'images'),) works with 127.0.0.1:8000/static/something.jpg but STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, ''),) doesn't work with 127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/something.jpg

Comment: Right, so it should work with either `/` or `/images/`. Unless you copy all static files under `site_media` into `site_media/images`. Or add both dirs in `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, ""), os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "images"), )`

Comment: STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, ""),    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "images"), ) doesn't work with 127.0.0.1:8000/static/something.jpg(!) and 127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/something.jpg. I got warning "ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting"

Comment: Yep, that's right actually. STATIC_ROOT is used only for `manage.py collectstatic` command. You don't need it if don't use `collectstatic`. Just leave it empty, and use `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('%s/site_media/' % PROJECT_DIR, '%s/site_media/images/' % PROJECT_DIR), )`. But you should not need the both anyway...