# How to make my css files to work in django

Tags: django

I am new to django but have some relative skills in python. I just started building a project in django and so far I have been able to create an app within my project. Also, I have been able to link the index.html file of my website to django and can successfully view it after running the server on the command prompt. But here are my questions;

1. How do i make the css, img & js files to work with my index.html?

Thanks to you guys for the responses so far, but still the index.html page loads on the localhost address but it doesn't apply the img,css and js scripts. It only loads the html. Although i have tried to use the method stated by the 2nd person that responded to my post but still no luck.

Comment: You can find an approach to your problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033571/using-static-files-with-the-django-virtual-server

Comment: The explanation on staticfiles on the django web page didn't really help. But thanks all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small demo for very basic css/img usage with the development-server: `python manage.py runserver`. You should not use this for production. 
For the user input/output you should have a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/).

**filestructure**

```
project
  |- static
  |   |- css
  |   |   |- stuff.css
  |- media
  |   |- images
  |   |   |- love.jpg
  |- templates
  |- urls.py
  |- __init__.py
  |- manage.py
  |- settings.py
```

**base.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/stuff.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <h1>I like django!</h1>
   <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/love.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
# example windows
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': 'C:/python25/lib/site-packages/project/media/', 'show_indexes': True}),
# example *ix
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/usr/lib/python25/site-packages/project/static/', 'show_indexes': True}),
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, but after making use of what you  have described up here, it still didn't work and i don't know what could be responsible for that. But i would be glad if you could add further clarifications to get me out of this mess. Or better still, 'path' should be the absolute path of the media and static files?

Comment: no, `path` is just a variable for the view `django.views.static.serve`. So if you type `http://example.com/media/stuff.jpg` there will be `stuff.jpg` in the `path` variable. What errors do you get if you try to access the files? You could update your question to post the errors.

Comment: I think i didn't specify the right path in the urls.py, maybe you should help me out with a specific example. Like the way you analyzed the file structure above. For example, with the stuff.jpg you used, that is just one file. Do i need to do that for all the related files(Css,js,img)

Comment: In my example this path 'C:/python25/lib/site-packages/project/media/' has to point to the directory where your images and css are stored.

Comment: Thanks for your responses so far, but i still have another question. What should be in 'path' here:                              (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': 'C:/python25/lib/site-packages/project/static/', 'show_indexes': True}),  if i have my css and js files in C:\Users\CIRCUIT ATLANTIC 1\Desktop\nameofapp and img files in C:\Users\CIRCUIT ATLANTIC 1\Desktop\nameofapp\media

Comment: put your css and js files into `C:\Users\CIRCUIT ATLANTIC 1\Desktop\nameofapp\media` and then only add `(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': 'C:/Users/CIRCUIT ATLANTIC 1/Desktop/nameofapp/media/', 'show_indexes': True}),` to your `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those that responded to my question, my static files are now active. I had to add RequestContext in my project view to make the {{STATIC_URL}} in the html file active.

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('Calculator/index.html',
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))