# Django CSS & Static Media Not Loading

Tags: django, django-templates

So I've been hitting my head against the wall on this for the last hour and can't seem to figure out why none of the static media (CSS, Images, JS etc) when my template is rendered. 
Could someone please help me find out why adjustments I need to make? Below are snippets from Settings.py, Index.html and stylesheet please let me know if more is needed.

My static files are located in the following directory:
/djangoproject/website/static

```
Settings.py    -  Located /djangoproject/djangoprojectname/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,
"/static/"))

STATIC_URL = '../website/static/'
```

Here's a snippet from my index.html that is supposed to be calling the css style sheet with {{ STATIC_URL }}

```
Index.html  - Location /djangoproject/website/templates/  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css">
```

Location of CSS StyleSheet

```
style.css - Location /djangoproject/website/static/css/
```

Comment: When the page renders, what do you see in the source where `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is in the template?

Comment: /projects/djangoproject/website/static/css/style.css  and that's the correct path as far as i can tell... it's just still not pulling the file... Was there something that I was supposed to maybe add to the urls.py or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819395/how-to-make-my-css-files-to-work-in-django/12821074#12821074 this might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Django docs:

> If {{ STATIC_URL }} isn't working in your template, you're probably
>   not using RequestContext when rendering the template.
>
> As a brief refresher, context processors add variables into the
>   contexts of every template. However, context processors require that
>   you use RequestContext when rendering templates. This happens
>   automatically if you're using a generic view, but in views written by
>   hand you'll need to explicitly use RequestContext To see how that
>   works, and to read more details, check out [Subclassing Context:RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are setting `STATIC_URL` to a path, when it should be set to, well, a URL. You need to set this to the web address of the folder that contains your css files, for example:

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://mydomain.com/static_files/'
```

Try to find your CSS file online by typing the address you expect it to be into your browser. Once you find the CSS file this way, just copy the root URL that got you there.