# Django Static Files - CSS not working

Tags: python, django, django-urls, static-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django and Serving Static Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179453/django-and-serving-static-files)

I am with one problem to load CSS at base.html. I put all css files at the directory /static.

At `urls.py` I put this code:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
           { 'document_root': '/home/bkcherry/botstore/botstore/static' }),
    )
```

And at base.html i put the following:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css.css" />
```

When I go to the main.html, the css style is not working. I need to configure the settings.py `MEDIA_ROOT`, `MEDIA_URL` or `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: what happens if you just point your browser to http://whatever.com/static/css.css ?

Comment: This could help, too. Also don't miss to pass RequestContext. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819395/how-to-make-my-css-files-to-work-in-django/12821074#12821074

Answer (score 1):

you must **not** use MEDIA_ROOT or MEDIA_URL this is for uploaded media not your static content, and you do not need to setup URL patterns as that is only for django 1.2 or " if you are using some other server for local development": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development

you need to have your static files in:
botstore/botstore/static/botstore/css.css

then use:

```
HOME_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(HOME_ROOT, 'staticfiles')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

then in your HTML you can refer to your static files thus:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}botstore/css.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a slash at the end of your path, ie `'/home/bkcherry/botstore/botstore/static/'`

Comment: I put the slash at the end at MEDIA_ROOT and its working now!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you check official documentation

```
from django.conf import settings

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

MEDIA_ROOT should have / on the end ([https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-MEDIA_ROOT))

Comment: Thx all, it's working now!! ;)

I fix the code at urls.py:

if settings.DEBUG:

    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    )

And i configure the settings.py:

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/bkcherry/botstore/botstore/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/static/'

And now the method GET found the directory.