# STATIC_ROOT doesn't find my static files

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles

I'm newbie in Django and I'm trying to find a way to load my css files in my project. Here is my `settings.py` file

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    #"django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Uncomment the following to make Django tests pass:
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

I got a way to do it using the variable `STATICFILES_DIRS`, but it won't work together with the others similars variables.

What should I do to fix it?

EXTRA INFORMATIONS:

My `base.html` file static files call:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'icomoon_style.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
```

My folders disposal:

- OntoLogica (main folder)

  - Ontologica (project folder)
  - static folder

    - icomoon_style.css
    - style.css
    - css folder
    - bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way that solved my case. It was found in this site: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

What I've to do:

Add the line `PROJECT_ROOT` and the change the line `STATIC_ROOT` to:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
```

With this I could add the line `STATICFILES_DIRS` without any trouble:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

It worked perfectly for me and I hope it helps someone else too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

set static path in a correct way. Get an idea from my project.

settings.py

```
import os
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

sys.path.append(join(dirname(__file__), "../applications"))
PROJECT_ROOT = abspath(dirname(__file__))

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My structure of files:

```
Main directory
              project dir
                        settings.py
                        urls.py
              media
              static folder.
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work. Still getting 404 in my static files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033571/using-static-files-with-the-django-virtual-server?rq=1 this will help you, if you find this correct plz tick it correct.

Comment: I actually found an answer... Going to post this soon... But I appreciate your attention and help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the "Warning" section of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#static-root)

> This [STATIC_ROOT] should be an initially empty destination directory for collecting your static files from their permanent locations into one directory for ease of deployment; **it is not a place to store your static files permanently**.

So you should use `STATICFILES_DIRS` to point to your static files.

And lastly make sure that you use `{% load staticfiles %}` in your templates to load your static files.